# secrets-store-csi-driver not able to convert YAML to JSON

Tags: helm3

```
Error: YAML parse error on secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/crds-upgrade-hook.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 26: could not find expected ':'
│
│   with helm_release.secrets-store-csi-driver,
│   on aws-secrets-csi.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "secrets-store-csi-driver":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "secrets-store-csi-driver" {
```

I am getting above error while using secrets-stores-csi-driver, using module for all my infrastructure.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Are you writing your own Helm chart (in which case, make sure to include any relevant template code), or just trying to deploy a third-party CSI driver (not on topic for Stack Overflow, try [devops.se] or [sf])?